# How much throughput can Datomic Free handle?

Tags: limit, datomic

How much data can the free version of Datomic handle in terms of storage and throughput? As far as I know, the free transactor uses H2 to store a local embedded database.

What stops me from using this in production, ignoring the obvious lack of storage redundancy and limited number of peers (1)?

Answer (score 1):

Datomic Pro starter edition is probably more of a go-to than the free edition since it supports all of the storage services as the licensed pro version. In terms of local storage and throughput, I'd say it can store up to the amount of space is available on the disk. The transactor handles all writes, so I'd imagine your only potential bottlenecks for throughput would be the hard disk or, if you're throwing tons of transactions at it, it would be waiting for the indexing jobs to complete as your data grows. Indexing can get computationally expensive over time and it's best to have GC and excision jobs in place if you're handling that much volume.